# como actualizar un reporte de crystal report en visual basic

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

tengo un reporte de listado de clientes para llamar la visualizacion de los datos en el reporte uso este codigo:

```
    Dim crystalrpt As New ReportDocument()
    crystalrpt.Load("C:\Users\Samuel Susana\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SistemadeventaPOO\SistemadeventaPOO\CrystalReportclientes.rpt")
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalrpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

pero si en la ejecucion del programa añado un cliente a mi tabla y luego llamo ese reporte el cliente que agrege no se muestra en la lista

Comment: Y cuando vuelves a compilar o ejecutar, te aparece el cliente?

Comment: NO, ese es el punto si lo hago en report viewer si me aparece inmediatamente

Answer (score 0):

Aquí de tejo una manera de poder actualizar reportes y no trabajes con reportes fijos sino dinámicos.

```
Sub REPORTE_COMUNICADOS(codigo As String)
    Dim rpt As New ReporteComunicado
    Try
        Dim Tabla As DataSet
        Dim existe As Boolean
        Dim cad As String

        cad = " exec [SP_REPORTE_COMUNICADO] '" & codigo & "' "
        Tabla = lsql.CARGAR_DATASET(cad)
        existe = System.IO.File.Exists("C:\XSD_COLTENE\LOGISTICA\REPORTE_COMUNICADOS.XSD")
        If existe = False Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\XSD_COLTENE")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\XSD_COLTENE\LOGISTICA")
            Dim URL As String = "C:\XSD_COLTENE\LOGISTICA\REPORTE_COMUNICADOS.XSD"
            Tabla.WriteXmlSchema(URL)
        End If
        rpt.SetDataSource(Tabla)
        REPORTES_BLANCO.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        REPORTES_BLANCO.Text = "REPORTE_COMUNICADOS"
        REPORTES_BLANCO.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        REPORTES_BLANCO.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

luego llamas al botón de esta manera

```
imp.REPORTE_COMUNICADOS(codigo)
```

' tu conexion [Si trabas en N capas cambia a la conexion que tienes echa]

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí te dejo una imagen ya que el codigo no se ve igual.

Comment: Te invito a dar un recorrido de como [responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para tu respuesta sea de utilidad